# Class * was removed because the Java implemented interface type '*<java.lang.Integer, T>' could not be found. Error binding xamarin android aar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, logrocket

- I have tried to binding a AAR library. LogRocket android but i getting the issue"

> obj/Debug/api.xml.class-parse : warning BG8605: The Java type 'com.logrocket.protobuf.Internal.MapAdapter.Converter<java.lang.Integer, T>' could not be found (are you missing a Java reference jar/aar or a Java binding library NuGet?)
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Bindings.ClassParse.targets(38,5): obj/Debug/api.xml.class-parse warning BG8605: The Java type 'com.logrocket.protobuf.Internal.MapAdapter.Converter<java.lang.Integer, T>' could not be found (are you missing a Java reference jar/aar or a Java binding library NuGet?)
> obj/Debug/api.xml.class-parse : warning BG8605: The Java type 'com.logrocket.protobuf.SmallSortedMap<FieldDescriptorType, java.lang.Object>' could not be found (are you missing a Java reference jar/aar or a Java binding library NuGet?)
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Bindings.ClassParse.targets(38,5): obj/Debug/api.xml.class-parse warning BG8605: The Java type 'com.logrocket.protobuf.SmallSortedMap<FieldDescriptorType, java.lang.Object>' could not be found (are you missing a Java reference jar/aar or a Java binding library NuGet?)
> obj/Debug/api.xml.class-parse : warning BG8605: The Java type 'java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction<sun.misc.Unsafe>' could not be found (are you missing a Java reference jar/aar or a Java binding library NuGet?)
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Bindings.ClassParse.targets(38,5): obj/Debug/api.xml.class-parse warning BG8605: The Java type 'java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction<sun.misc.Unsafe>' could not be found (are you missing a Java reference jar/aar or a Java binding library NuGet?)
> The class '[Class] com.logrocket.protobuf.Internal.MapAdapter.1' was removed because the Java implemented interface type 'com.logrocket.protobuf.Internal.MapAdapter.Converter<java.lang.Integer, T>' could not be found.
> The class '[Class] com.logrocket.protobuf.SmallSortedMap.1' was removed because the Java base type 'com.logrocket.protobuf.SmallSortedMap<FieldDescriptorType, java.lang.Object>' could not be found.
> The class '[Class] com.logrocket.protobuf.UnsafeUtil.1' was removed because the Java implemented interface type 'java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction<sun.misc.Unsafe>' could not be found.

The dependency of this library only the package Annotation

```
{
  "name": "releaseVariantReleaseRuntimePublication",
  "attributes": {
    "org.gradle.category": "library",
    "org.gradle.dependency.bundling": "external",
    "org.gradle.libraryelements": "aar",
    "org.gradle.usage": "java-runtime"
  },
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "group": "androidx.annotation",
      "module": "annotation",
      "version": {
        "requires": "1.1.0"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Any idea?

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Tks for reply, I upload the source to repo: https://github.com/bulubuloa/LogRocketBinding

Comment: After I build the demo you shared, the output window has a number of errors. And these errors are not the errors you said.